# react-select does not change label with defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Why does react-select don't change label, but change value?

```
const options = [
  { label: 'One', value: 'One' },
  { label: 'Two', value: 'Two' },
];

<Select
  defaultValue={{label: "One", value: "One"}}
  options=options
/>
```

Comment: Actually I wrapped this Select to redux-form <Field> component

Comment: I added default value for initialValues in redux-form in object format and it works. Help you all `initialValues: { type: {label: "One", value: "One"} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Select default value takes an object to set the default value. the issue in your code is very simple,

1- you need to bind options by wrapping them in {} like `{options}`

and then to set the defaultValue:

2- `defaultValue={options[1]}` or `defaultValue={{ label: 'Two', value: 'Two' }}`

check the example on sandbox:
[sample example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-dust-bsz0g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

just to be clear the label will only change the text being displayed in select, but the actual value is bounded by `value` key in the object

Comment: It works but only for pure Select, but doesn't with redux-form <Field> wrapped

Answer (score 0):

The defaultValue prop will only take in a value. For your example if you set defaultValue to "One", it will automatically set the label to the corresponding option above. An example would be:

```
const options = [
  { label: 'One', value: 'One' },
  { label: 'Two', value: 'Two' },
];

//the defaultValue will look inside the options array and use the label where the value is the same
<Select
  defaultValue="One"
  options=options
/>
```

check out more here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select